# How can my application code know whether the app is being tested with testcafe?

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have a suite of tests running with TestCafe. In one component, I need to know whether to expose some data to the window based on whether the application is running in testcafe or not, i.e.

```
if (window.Testcafe === true) {
    window.property = data;
}
```

This is possible with Cypress, another test framework, which exposes window.Cypress.
I've tried setting a property on window from the testcafe tests/fixtures, using code to the effect of

```
test('Test 1', async t => {
    await t.eval(() => {window.Testcafe = true});
    const val = await t.eval(() => window.Testcafe);
    // val === true
})
// In component window.Testcafe is false
```

I'm open to other approaches (besides window properties). Has anyone else done something similar?

Answer (score 5):

TestCafe adds some properties to the `window` object which can help you determine that your site is working with TestCafe. For example, you can check the `window['%hammerhead%']` property. If it exists, it means that TestCafe works.

However, I need to mention that it's not a public API. It's hardly will be changed in the future, but it is still not a 100% solid solution.

Could you please describe your scenario in detail? If many users find it helpful, we can consider implementing this feature in the future.

In addition, I want to mention that you can create feature requests in the TestCafe repository using the following [form](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=feature_request.md)

Answer (score 2):

The component has already loaded when the test starts its execution.

So setting the `TestCafe` variable inside the test is too late.

One workaround to test TestCafe hosting is:

```
if ( window.localStorage.nativeStorageKey && window.localStorage.nativeStorageKey.startsWith('hammerhead')) {
    window.property = data;
}
```